# python: how to write a generic file reader with format plugins

Tags: python, image-processing, polymorphism, filereader

I'm trying to write a generic reader of all sorts of medical image formats that 
we come accross. I thought, let's learn from the pros and went to imitate how
[PIL generically reads files](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/formats.htm) ("Python Imaging Library", Formats).

As I understand it, PIL has an open function that loops throuh a list of possible 
accept functions. When one works, it uses the related factory function to instantiate
the appropriate object.

So I went to do this and my (stripped-down) efforts are here:

```
pluginID = []     # list of all registered plugin IDs
OPEN = {}         # plugins have open and (maybe) accept functions as a tuple

_initialized = False

import os, sys

def moduleinit():
    '''Explicitly initializes the library.  This function 
    loads all available file format drivers.

    This routine has been lifted from PIL, the Python Image Library'''

    global _initialized
    global pluginID
    if _initialized:
        return 

    visited = {}

    directories = sys.path

    try:
        directories = directories + [os.path.dirname(__file__)]
    except NameError:
        pass

    # only check directories (including current, if present in the path)
    for directory in filter(isDirectory, directories):
        fullpath = os.path.abspath(directory)
        if visited.has_key(fullpath):
            continue
        for file in os.listdir(directory):
            if file[-19:] == "TestReaderPlugin.py":
                f, e = os.path.splitext(file)
                try:
                    sys.path.insert(0, directory)
                    try: # FIXME: this will not reload and hence pluginID 
                        # will be unpopulated leading to "cannot identify format"
                        __import__(f, globals(), locals(), [])
                    finally:
                        del sys.path[0]
                except ImportError:
                    print f, ":", sys.exc_value
        visited[fullpath] = None

    if OPEN:
        _initialized = True
        return 1

class Reader:
    '''Base class for image file format handlers.'''
    def __init__(self, fp=None, filename=None):

        self.filename = filename

        if isStringType(filename):
            import __builtin__
            self.fp = __builtin__.open(filename) # attempt opening

        # this may fail if not implemented
        self._open() # unimplemented in base class but provided by plugins

    def _open(self):
        raise NotImplementedError(
            "StubImageFile subclass must implement _open"
            )


# this is the generic open that tries to find the appropriate handler
def open(fp):
    '''Probe an image file

    Supposed to attempt all opening methods that are available. Each 
    of them is supposed to fail quickly if the filetype is invalid for its 
    respective format'''

    filename=fp

    moduleinit() # make sure we have access to all the plugins

    for i in pluginID:
        try:
            factory, accept = OPEN[i]
            if accept:
                fp = accept(fp)
                # accept is expected to either return None (if unsuccessful) 
                # or hand back a file handle to be used for opening                                 
                if fp:
                    fp.seek(0)  
                    return factory(fp, filename=filename) 
        except (SyntaxError, IndexError, TypeError): 
                pass # I suppose that factory is allowed to have these 
                # exceptions for problems that weren't caught with accept()
                # hence, they are simply ignored and we try the other plugins

    raise IOError("cannot identify format")

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Plugin registry

def register_open(id, factory, accept=None):
    pluginID.append(id)
    OPEN[id] = factory, accept

# --------------------------------------------------------------------
# Internal:

# type stuff
from types import  StringType

def isStringType(t):
    return isinstance(t, StringType)

def isDirectory(f):
    '''Checks if an object is a string, and that it points to a directory'''
    return isStringType(f) and os.path.isdir(f)
```

The important bit behind the scenes is a registration of all format plugins upon
the first time an attempt is made to open a file (moduleinit). Every eligible
plugin must be in an accessible path and named *TestReaderPlugin.py. It will 
get (dynamically) imported. Each plugin module has to call a register_open 
to provide an ID, a method to create the file and an accept function to test 
candidate files.

An example plugin will look like this:

```
import TestReader

def _accept(filename):
    fp=open(filename,"r")
    # we made it here, so let's just accept this format
    return fp

class exampleTestReader(TestReader.Reader):
    format='example'

    def _open(self):
        self.data = self.fp.read()

TestReader.register_open('example', exampleTestReader, accept=_accept)
```

TestReader.open() is the function that a user will use:

```
import TestReader
a=TestReader.open(filename) # easy
```

So - where is the problem? Firstly, I'm still on the search for the pythonic 
way. Is this it? My reasons to doubt it is that the magic in the moduleinit
stage looks messy. It is copied straight from PIL. Main problem: If you 
reload(TestReader), it will all stop working because ID gets initialized to [], 
but the plugins will not get reloaded.

Are there better ways to set up a generic reader that
1. allows a simple open(filename) call for all formats and
2. requires only nicely encapsulated plugins to be provided for whatever format you want.
3. works on reloads?

Answer (score 1):

Some guidelines:

1. Use the concept of "peek" into a buffer to test if there is data data you could understand.
2. Knowing the name of the importer is something a user does not want to know (what if you have 100 importers)
   use a "facade" interface **medicimage.open(filepath)**
3. To work on reload you have to implement a little bit of logic, there are exaples out there   on how to achieve that

Comment: I think I'm doing 1 and 2. (1) is up to the implemented accept method. The example given simply accepts any format without even as much as a peek but could if needed. (2) is achieved by having TestReader.open be that facade interface you mention. Can you be more specific about (3)? Two options that come to mind: (a) check if _initialized has been defined and don't reset pluginID if true. (b) some variant of deep reload. Neither of these sound very pythonic hence the question ...